# Mysql replace path

Tags: mysql, path

I have next table:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  movietype int(11) NOT NULL,
  category_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  movie_display_name mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  movie_path mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  movie_icon mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  notes mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY id (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO movies (id, movietype, movie_display_name, movie_path) VALUES(
  1009, 1,  'Movie Name',   '["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2623.mp4"]'
);
```

I need to replace every path in this database but I cant find the right way

I need this
**["\/home\/user\/example\/kids\/movies\/movie.mkv"]**
change to **["\/home\/user\/examplekids\/movie.mkv"]**

replace `\/kids\/movies` with `kids`

Try this... not working

```
UPDATE movies 
SET 
    moviepath = REPLACE(moviepath,
        "%\/kids\/movies%",
        "%kids%")
WHERE
    movietype = 1;
```

I try every thing but nothing work

Comment: Please look the fiddle. Is it suitable for you: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=98f1b2bb164d3ed1791d1999d7aed88a&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I think it's different I dont know why, but doesn't work... I think it's because its an array of paths..

Comment: I dont know what is samplefiddle... but...here a sample
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2623.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2622.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2619.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2618.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2617.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2610.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2609.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2603.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2597.mp4"] ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2590.mp4"]

Comment: Please provide `movies` table structure, You can get it by `SHOW CREATE TABLE movies;`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movietype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_display_name` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `movie_path` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `movie_icon` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `notes` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37365 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Perfect! Now provide couple of sample rows. Run `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movietype = 1;` and post the result

Comment: example:
`1009 1 Movie Name ["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2623.mp4"]`

Comment: It looks work here: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=de95b966114941dc2e8319fdee7105de&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
UPDATE movies 
SET 
    moviepath = REPLACE(moviepath,
        "/kids/movies",
        "/kids/")
WHERE
    movietype = 1;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from movies;
+----------------------------------+
| moviepath                        |
+----------------------------------+
| /home/user/example/kids/movie.mk |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select moviepath, REPLACE(moviepath,"/kids/movies","/xxxxkids/") from movies;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| moviepath                        | REPLACE(moviepath,"/kids/movies","/xxxxkids/") |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| /home/user/example/kids/movie.mk | /home/user/example/kids/movie.mk               |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> update movies set moviepath =  REPLACE(moviepath,"/kids/movies","/xxxxkids/");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from movies;
+----------------------------------+
| moviepath                        |
+----------------------------------+
| /home/user/example/kids/movie.mk |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: I already try that, and didnt work... /kids/movies to kids ... \\/kids\\/movies to kids

Comment: it works. see the Sample from @Slava Rozhnev . there you can remove the backslshs and see the result. There is no reason to escape the the slash

Comment: If i put 
`UPDATE movies SET moviepath = REPLACE(moviepath, "moviename.mkv", "moviename2.mkv") WHERE movietype = 1;`

It work, but if I put some /path it dont

Comment: are the backslashs in the table ? show the output from **select movieath from movies where movietype = 1 limit 10;**

Comment: I don't know if it's because it's an array ... but that dont work

Comment: `["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2623.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2622.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2619.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2618.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2617.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2610.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2609.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2603.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2597.mp4"]
["\/home\/user\/movies\/kids\/2590.mp4"]`

Comment: i have add a sample in my answer